# Meteor Gravatar appears on user page but not within the list of rooms

Tags: javascript, meteor, gravatar

Each user has a gravatar or a profile image if uploaded. A list of rooms is shown (each has 2 parties). It shows the opposite party gravatar/uploaded image and his or her username.

**Problem:** 
The Gravatars do not appear but the uploaded images (if uploaded) appear. Gravatar does appear on the user's profile page (with params as the userId).

In console, `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` returns ok. So is the md5hash which returns correct user details.

**The user's profile:**

```
profileImg 
  - uploaded 
username 
md5hash
emails
```

**Each room contains**

```
owner, receiver, people: [owner, receiver], id //roomId
```

**allRooms.js**

```
    Template.allRooms.onCreated(function () {
       this.autorun(() => {
          this.subscribe('rooms');
          this.subscribe('allUsers');
          $.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: "mthh" }); 
       });
    });
    Template.allRooms.helpers({
       chatPerson(){ 
          return this.owner === Meteor.userId() ? Meteor.users.findOne(this.receiver) : Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner); 
       },
     });
```

**allRooms.html**

```
 {{#each rooms}}

     {{#with chatPerson}} <!-- doesnt work if {{#if chatPerson}} ..nothing shows -->
        {{#if profileImg.upload}} 
           <img src="{{c.url profileImg.upload format=format gravity='faces' mode='thumb' crop='thumb' width=60 height=60}}"> <!-- uploaded pic shows up --> 
        {{else}}
           <div class="avatar" style="background: url({{ avatar 60 chatPerson}}; height: 60px; width: 60px; float:left;"></div> <!-- if no uploaded pic, gravatar doesnt show up but console.log shows user object details and md5hash number --> 
        {{/if}}
     {{/with}}

     {{chatPerson.username}} roomId: {{_id}} <!-- shows up --> 
{{/each}}
```

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', () => {   
    return Meteor.users.find({ 
        fields: { username: 1, emails: 1, profileImg: 1, md5hash: 1}
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you post your publications for reference here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a helper to generate the avatar url such as:

```
Template.registerHelper( 'avatar',( avatarSize, user ) => {
  let md5hash = ( user && user.md5hash ) ? user.md5hash : this.md5hash;      
  md5hash = md5hash || "3eda6fcd3204ef285fa52176c28c4d3e"; // Equivalent to Gravatar.hash( 'none@none.com' );
  return Gravatar.imageUrl( md5hash, { secure: true, size: avatarSize, d: 'mm', rating: 'pg' } );  
});
```

Then you need to pass it a valid user object. In your code:

```
<div class="avatar" style="background: url({{ avatar 60 currentUser}}; height: 60px; width: 60px; float:left;"></div>
```

`currentUser` is not defined. Replace that with `this` which is the user context inside your `{{#with}}` block:

```
<div class="avatar" style="background: url({{ avatar 60 this}}; height: 60px; width: 60px; float:left;"></div>
```

Comment: `currentUser` is just an evocative variable name. Whatever you put there has to resolve to a `user` object that has an `md5hash` property.

Comment: `this` did not work, neither did `this.user` or `this.chatPerson`. hmm Let me know if you need some tests? I can post results here.

Comment: Fixed a cut/paste error in my template helper code there... Try putting a breakpoint or doing `console.log(user)` in the `avatar` helper and make sure the helper is getting a user object passed to it and that the object has an `md5hash` key.

Comment: Let's jump to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143310/meteor and continue there.